# echo $JAVA_HOME not returning jdk location

Tags: echo, java-home

When I type in echo $JAVA_HOME, I get $JAVA_HOME instead of the location of the jdk.
I set the path from the environment variables correctly:

Variable name : JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try `echo %JAVA_HOME%` instead of `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

The first is for Windows (I'm assuming it's windows based on your filepath), the one you're using is for Linux.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, when I typed "echo $JAVA_HOME" I was getting blank, and I resolved it by following these instructions:

$ vim .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .bash_profile

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home

Reference:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Take a deep breath and refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how do I write a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you may setup and confirm the environment variable like this:

```
~$ sudo apt install default-jdk
~$ sudo nano /etc/environment
# ADD below line
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
~$ source /etc/environment
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Above commands are:

1. install jdk
2. edit environment file
3. apply edited environment variable
4. show $JAVA_HOME

Answer (score -1):

**Linux:**

$ vi ~/.bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin/java

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin

$ source ~/.bash_profile

**Verification:**

$ echo $JAVA_HOME

$ echo $PATH

$ which java